# Does Ubuntu run from a CD/DVD save data ONLY in memory?

Tags: live-environment

If I create a proper LiveCD and run the OS from the disc does it save any information on a hard-drive or is it ALL saved to the PC's memory? I've looked around for a clear, direct "yes/no" answer to this question but I can't seem find it anywhere. Common sense would say yes but you never know and what I need to do requires an OS that does not use Flash(usb) or Magnetic(hd) storage of any kind while in operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the answers to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104003/will-ubuntu-live-cd-dvd-work-with-no-hard-drive-installed), we can safely believe that no data is stored on the hard disk unless we choose to save it to hard disk(persistence).

As for a definitve answer check out this post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898301/where-is-data-on-a-non-persistant-live-cd-stored) which explains that it is a `ramdisk`.

Quoting from the Stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3898314/749232) to the above said question:

> Believe it or not, it's a ramdisk :) All live distros mount a
>   temporary hard disk in RAM memory. The process is completely
>   user-transparent and is all because of the magic of Linux kernel.
>
> The OS, in fact, first allocates an area of your RAM memory into a
>   virtual device, then mounts it as a regular hard drive in your file
>   system.
>
> Once you reboot, you lose all your data from that ramdrive.

For more detailed information regarding this, check out the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD#Technique) on Live Cd explaining the `technique` of its working.

Answer (score 0):

Booting an Ubuntu live session from a live CD will not be able to write data on a harddrive unless the drive was mounted.

But there is a caveat to this in case you are concerned about data security issues.

If you boot your live CD on a system with an existing **swap partition** the live environment may also use this as swap. We therefore have to disable swap after booting the live environment. See this question on how to do this:

- [Prevent LiveCD using existing swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8626/prevent-livecd-using-existing-swap-partition)