# Will I lose my data if I turned the pc off, while using Ubuntu on Live USB?

Tags: live-usb, user-data

Hi  now I'm using Ubuntu using flash memory without install it , And I  installed some program & downloaded  some files. If I turn the PC off will I lose my  data or if I install the system now will I lose the data ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Ubuntu run from a CD/DVD save data ONLY in memory?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/267703/does-ubuntu-run-from-a-cd-dvd-save-data-only-in-memory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the LiveCD runs in a ramdisk which means that when shutting the computer off that all data will be lost. However, you can save this data to an external device (i.e. flash drive or if you wanted maybe Dropbox). The same will happen when installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you run USB pendrive in persistent mode, yes you will  lose your data...

More here:https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent